# Hbase Import Table Error

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I was trying to import the data from one hbase(v0.98.4) to another hbase(v0.98.13).

I have exported the data using the below command -

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver export 'tblname' /path/
```

But I am not able to import it using the below command -

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver import 'tblname' /hdfs/path/
```

I get the below deprecation messages as well as an Exception thrown -
[image]

[image]

Is it becoz of version conflicts between source db and destination db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to solve it. All I had to do was create an empty table with same metadata and then import it. :)

Comment: Have you identified any difference in usage of Driver with arguments v/s Export/Import classes

Comment: @Ramzy I did try that too but no big difference in term of time to import the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the commands [here](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/ops_mgt.html#export) for Hbase versions above 0.94. May be you are using generalized Map reduce class and giving export and import as arguments, when the actual classes Export and Import are present. Hope it helps. Happy coding